# Javascript variable scope inside for loop

Tags: javascript

How do I maintain access to the `i` variable inside my for loop below? I'm trying to learn, not just get the answer, so a bit of explanation would be very helpful. Thank you!

```
var el, 
    len = statesPolyStrings.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    el = document.getElementById(statesPolyStrings[i]);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(el, 'mouseover', function() {
        $("#"+statesPolyStrings[i]).addClass("highlight");
        statesPolyObjects[i].setOptions({ strokeWeight: '2' });
    });
}
```

Comment: You want access to `i` outside of the for loop? You already has access to `i` inside of the for loop.

Comment: I want to access it within the function addDomListener within the for loop. Anywhere you see an i in the above code I want to use i as defined and incremented in the for loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

All of your callbacks share the same `i` variable.
When the event handler actually runs, `i` is after the end of the array.

You need to wrap the loop body in a self-invoking function that takes `i` as a parameter.
This way, each iteration will get its own, unchanging, `i` variable.

For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < statesPolyStrings.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        ...
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example by correcting my code? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Got it and now understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < statesPolyStrings.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById(statesPolyStrings[i]), 'mouseover', function() {
        $("#"+statesPolyStrings[i]).addClass("highlight");
        statesPolyObjects[i].setOptions({ strokeWeight: '2' });
        });
    })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick with self-invoking functions works fine: it creates a new scope (maybe google for 'scope in functions javascript') and therefore handles `i` as a different variable and delivers the right value to your event listener callback function.

But you actually don't need to find your element **again** with jQuery as you already assigned an event listener to it and inside your function you have a reference to your element with **`this`**.

And as you're using jQuery anyhow, it's then easy to find the correct index (your `i`) of `statesPolyObjects` with [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) passing the id of your element and the `statesPolyStrings` array (assuming you're dealing with unique IDs. If not, `$("#"+statesPolyStrings[i])` would also fail, as it takes the first it finds).

```
var el;

for (var i = 0, len = statesPolyStrings.length; i < len; i++) {
    el = document.getElementById(statesPolyStrings[i]);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(el, 'mouseover', function(event) {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        statesPolyObjects[$.inArray(this.id, statesPolyStrings)].
            setOptions({ strokeWeight: '2' });
    });
}
```

If you still want to stick with the self-invoking function you should anyhow change the following line:

```
("#"+statesPolyStrings[i]).addClass("highlight");
```

to

```
$(this).addClass("highlight");
```

If you're not familiar enough with **`this`** and events you might want to read this article:
http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/

You might have noticed that I also wrote the argument **`event`** inside the anonymous callback function. Try to `console.log` this event you get delivered for free with any event listener callback function and explore all the other things you have access to. For example, you can find the actual element you clicked on with `event.target` (as the actual mouseover might have happened to a child of your element). So:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(el, 'mouseover', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    ...
```

and open the console of your browser to see what event delivers...

Be aware though that `google.maps.event.addDomListener` passes something different then `document.body.addEventListener` and there is also a difference between browsers. jQuery.on() for example also delivers some different things in the event object, but there you can at least count on the same data in all browsers.