# Javascript can't read variable in function()

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

I have an example on this code:

```
<script>
    for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
            say("HELLO NUMBER " + i);
        }, i * 2000);
    }

    function say(text){
        alert(text);
    }
</script>
```

And output I need is :

**alert("HELLO NUMBER 1");**

**alert("HELLO NUMBER 2");**

But in this case, I still get output :

**alert("HELLO NUMBER 3");**

Anyone can help for this? thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954053/javascript-variable-scope-inside-for-loop

Comment: its about query search... but thanks for your suqestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classic problem with closure

```
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
    (function(num){
        setTimeout(function(){
            say("HELLO NUMBER " + num);
        }, num * 2000);

    })(i)
}

function say(text){
    alert(text);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Kwmt/2/)

You are using a closure variable `i` inside the `setTimeout` callback, whose value is evaluated only when the callback is executed by then the value of `i` will be updated by the outside loop

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

```
var out = [];
for(var i=0; i<3; ++i){
    out.push(i+1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        say("HELLO NUMBER " + out.shift());
    }, i * 2000);
}

function say(text){
    alert(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a closure for the value of i for each iteration:

```
for (var i=1; i<3; i++) {
    (function(j){
        setTimeout(function() { alert("HELLO NUMBER " + j); }, j*2000);
    })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function doSetTimeout(i) {
         setTimeout(function() { say("HELLO NUMBER " + i); }, 3000);
    }

    for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
        doSetTimeout(i);
    }

    function say(text){
    alert(text);
   }
</script>
```