# What is the equivalent of Java's final in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code that is not working correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var bt = new HrButton("btn" + i);                    
        bt.setOnclick(function() {
            alert(bt.name + " clicks = " + bt.cntClick);
            bt.cntClick = bt.cntClick + 1;
        });
        $("#container").append(bt.toHtml());
    }
});
```

How can I maintain three instances of `bt` within the function. As it stands now `bt` refers to `btn2` in each onclick.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You don't need final. You need a closure to properly scope the `bt` inside the `for` iteration, as blocks don't create scopes in JS.

Comment: what`s need and do you want to maintain 3rd variable ? for what ?

Comment: I don't know what code library you're using, but try using `this` instead of `bt` inside the click handler.

Comment: Check if the answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10954053/1331430)'s answer helps you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `setOnclick` is implemented nicely, you should probably be able to do:

```
bt.setOnclick(function() {
    alert(this.name + " clicks = " + this.cntClick);
    this.onclick = this.cntClick + 1;
});
```

Otherwise, you need to create a new scope for each callback function so that they each have their own `bt`. One way to do that would be:

```
bt.setOnclick(function(bt){
    return function(){
        alert(bt.name + " clicks = " + bt.cntClick);
        bt.onclick = bt.cntClick + 1;
    };
}(bt));
```

**Comment Response**

To implement setOnClick such that `this` refers to the relevant `HrButton` (rather than the `element`) within the callback, you can use the following code (works in modern browsers only, [unless you SHIM bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility)):

```
var self = this;
self.setOnClick = function(fnOnClick) {
    element.onclick = fnOnClick.bind(self);
};
```

Since you're using jQuery the following code will be a cross-browser equivalent:

```
var self = this;
self.setOnClick = function(fnOnClick) {
    element.onclick = $.proxy(fnOnClick, self);
};
```

Otherwise this will work in all browsers, without any libraries, and is only slightly less readable:

```
var self = this;
self.setOnClick = function(fnOnClick) {
    element.onclick = function(event) {
        return fnOnClick.call(self, event);
    };
};
```

Comment: is not really a library, is scenario for learning and how I can made a setOnClick implemented nicely if I have this.setOnClick(fnOnClick) { elemen.onclcik = fnOnCLick; ) where element is create from documente.createElement('button')

Comment: @rChavz Is `setOnclick` a function that you wrote yourself? Did either of the above codes solve your problem?

Comment: @rChavz I updated my answer with a few ways to implement `setOnClick`, so that you can use `this`.

Comment: so muchas gracias = thanks, one more question why you obfuscate this on self?

Comment: @rChavz It is necessary to make a copy of a reference to the object, so that you can refer to it within the function, since `this` refers to the calling context of the callback function (the `element`), and you want to refer to the `HrButton` which is `this` outside the callback.